# Google Sheets Join information from two pages with query & vlookup

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I know this has been asked several times, but I just can't seem to understand how to write the formula and I'm hoping to get some help.
Consider the following (example data) sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1t_I_stZmZea4sfGPsCu6GtBhGJJT16CZ-sEu7JubFKc/edit?usp=sharing

First, note that I am importing data on "API Data" utilizing importJSON().

My goal is to combine (join) data from two sheets. I need "dataseries cloudcover" from 'API data' and "Dataseries example,Dataseries example 1,Dataseries example 2" from 'join'.

I gave it a shot here:

```
=query('API data'!A:L,"Select " & vlookup(B:B,'API data'!B:L,3,FALSE) & ",B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L")
```

Here is a SS of what I would like to see
[image]

Comment: Your question can be greatly improved if you add a table to the question. [Tables](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) are a better alternative than spreadsheets to show your data structure.  If you share spreadsheets, make sure to also add images of your sheet to avoid closure of your question, as questions here must be [self](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455/) [contained](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/149892). [Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), when you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This formula can help you to get that data:

*Note: Just add the formula in A2*

```
={ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK('API data'!C2:C),"",ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP('API data'!C2:C,'API data'!C2:D25,2)))),ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(Join!A2:A),"",ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(Join!A2:A,Join!A2:D25,{2,3,4},FALSE))))}
```

And it will look like this:
[image]

**Edit:**

Editing and adding more information about the use of this formula.

The formula is constructed with 2 different VLookUps, 1 for each tab, and they are merged using:

`={First Array, Second Array}`

The first Array is:

`ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK('API data'!K2:K),"",ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP('API data'!K2:K,'API data'!K2:L25,2))))`

The second Array is:

`ARRAYFORMULA(IF(ISBLANK(Join!I2:I),"",ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP(Join!I2:I,Join!I2:L25,{2,3,4},FALSE))))`

The core part of the first array for this formula is:

`ARRAYFORMULA(VLOOKUP('API data'!K2:K,'API data'!K2:L25,2))`

The `IF(IsBlank(column,"",Vlookup)` will remove any empty value of the Array.

The same thing with the second Array, with the difference that I use an Array `{2,3,4}` to call all the columns in the second sheet.

**Reference:**

- [VLOOKUP function.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093318)
- [ARRAYFORMULA function.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [IF function.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [ISBLANK function.](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093290)

Comment: @StavenCross, if you need more information or step to step explanation please let me know.

Comment: This answer does exactly what I requested. However, while reviewing this answer, I've come to understand that what I really need, is not what I've asked for - I need a real database.